# How to create pandas dataframe from python dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a python dictionary below:

```
dict = {'stock1': (5,6,7), 'stock2': (1,2,3),'stock3': (7,8,9)};
```

I want to change dictionary to dataframe like:

[image]

How to write the code?

I use:

```
pd.DataFrame(list(dict.iteritems()),columns=['name','closePrice'])
```

But it will get wrong.
Could anyone help?

Comment: I have tried pd.DataFrame(dict),But it will show: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Answer (score 4):

You are overcomplicating the problem, just pass your dictionary into the `DataFrame` constructor:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'stock1': (5,6,7), 'stock2': (1,2,3),'stock3': (7,8,9)}
print(pd.DataFrame(d))
```

Prints:

```
   stock1  stock2  stock3
0       5       1       7
1       6       2       8
2       7       3       9
```

Comment: I have tried your method,But it will show:                                                           If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: @easyway Then the dictionary you gave as an example doesn't represent the dictionary your actual dictionary accurately. If it were the same form, that works in every version of pandas, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: **Do not name your variables python key words!**

```
dd = {'stock1': (5,6,7), 'stock2': (1,2,3),'stock3': (7,8,9)};
#pd.DataFrame(dd) Should work!

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dd, orient='columns')

   stock1  stock2  stock3
0       5       1       7
1       6       2       8
2       7       3       9
```